# UIScrollView doesn't zoom UIView after applying affine transformation to the latter

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, zooming, transformation

I'm struggling with this issues since two days now and I couldn't find a solution yet. My setup is pretty basic: I've got a UIScrollView, a UIView inside it, return the latter at viewForZoomingInScrollView and there's really nothing more than that. Actually, it works as expected. The issue comes when I add this line at viewDidLoad of my view controller:

```
viewForZooming.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
```

Then the scroll view doesn't zoom anymore. 
Is this related to the frame getting invalidated after transforming the view? Is there any workaround?

Thanks.